# Formula to identify invisible sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A               
1    Sheet1    =MID(CELL("filename",Sheet1!K1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet1!K1))+1,255)
2    Sheet2    =MID(CELL("filename",Sheet2!K1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet2!K1))+1,255)
3    Sheet3    =MID(CELL("filename",Sheet3!K1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet3!K1))+1,255)
4    Sheet4    =MID(CELL("filename",Sheet4!K1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet4!K1))+1,255)
5    Sheet5    =MID(CELL("filename",Sheet5!K1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet5!K1))+1,255)
6
7
```

In `Column A` there is a list of all sheets in the Excel file. 
 I list the sheets using the formula that you can see next to it.

All this works fine so far.

---

Now it can happen that some sheets in my spreadsheet are invisible (hidden). In this case I want that those sheets **do not appear** in the list above. Therefore, I wonder if there is a formula that can identify if a sheet is visible or not. Something like this:

```
IF MID(CELL("filename",Sheet1!K1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet1!K1))+1,255) = Invisible THEN ""
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you need a pair of Workbook_SheetActivate and Workbook_SheetDeactivate sub procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the purpose of this list... it seems like you're just duplicating the list of worksheet "tabs" shown at the bottom of the screen.

I sense *something* being made more complicated than necessary; either an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), or some duplicate data that you're trying to manage without reorganizing it. :-)

Regardless, based on my understanding of your question, there are no built-in functions to do what you need, but these VBA examples should give you some ideas:

This procedure lists all visible worksheets, in the Immediate Window (Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> from VBA to view it):

```
Sub ListSheets()  'list in immediate window
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then Debug.Print sht.Name
    Next sht
End Sub
```

This procedure is similar excep lists them on the active worksheet, leaving blanks for hidden sheets (like your example would imply):

```
Sub ListSheets()  'list on worksheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then Range("A" & sht.Index) = sht.Name
    Next sht
End Sub
```

This function can be called from a worksheet formula and lists the name of the worksheet you specify by index number. It returns `""` (empty string/nothing) if the worksheet is not set to Visible, or if it doesn't exist.

```
Function listSheet(shtNum As Long) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheets(shtNum).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then listSheet = Sheets(shtNum).Name
End Function
```

[image: img]

---

### Related note:

There are ***three*** types of worksheet visibility.

[image: img]

---

### More Info:

- [**MSDN: Worksheet.Visible Property** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Visible)

Comment: Hi ashleedawg, thanks a lot for help. Exactly, what I was looking for.